# Vba: Do While/ Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button titled "LOW STOCK" on my userform, I want the back color of this button to switch between yellow and salmon when Cell G3 > 0 (Cell G3 contains number of products below stock minimum limit).

The blinking will prompt the user to click the button inorder to display (via a pop up message box) numbers of products having low stock.

I inserted the code below in Userform_Initialize, but excel freezes up and displays on the title bar "Excel is Not Responding". Please I'll be glad to know where I went wrong.

```
Sub Userform_Initialize
    Do while sheet1.Cells(3, 7) > 0 
        btnLowStock.Backcolor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        btnLowStock.Backcolor = RGB(255, 128, 128)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You're never changing the value of `sheet1.Cells(3, 7)`, so your loop never terminates.

Comment: Note: In the theoretical case you got your loop working to check that cell's value you are going to need a waiting time to actually be able to see 'blinking'.

Comment: Thanks jsheeran and JvdV. How can I add a waiting time.  Thanks

Comment: @DeBruceLuc - Are you waiting for user input to change the value in `sheet1.Cells(3, 7)`?

Comment: @Enimativity -  Actually, the value in Cell G3 only changes when products are supplied and there is no low stock. Hence the value reverts to zero then the blinking should stop.

Comment: Check Application.OnTime (you will find examples on SO).  But whilst you might get it to work, it will be messy and you will probably regret it.  Better IMHO to make the button stand out another way.